# Tie-related question

Tags: rules

could you help me out please?

Just saw an episode of High Stakes Poker:

One player went all-in with AK, another one called with AQ. Neither of them made any hand after the river. But they split the pot.
My question is: Why didn't the AK win, since he had a stronger kicker (king)?

P.s. similar situation happens when I play on PokerStars.

P.p.s are there other tricky situations like these?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! This situation is not as tricky as it seems, the best 5-card hand from each player utilizing the cards on the board and their hand is found and if they are the same the pot is split evenly between the two players.

Comment: When you say "neither of them made any hand", that's not true. Every hand, every player makes the best 5-card hand out of his two plus the 5 on the board. There are many ways A-K and A-Q can split: perhaps the board was something like 9-9-7-7-5, and they are both playing two pair with A kicker (you can't play the K--poker hands have EXACTLY FIVE CARDS, no more, no fewer). Perhaps the board was a 6-high straight. Perhaps the board was a flush, and neither player had a card of that suit. Without knowing the board, we can't tell you why it was split.